# iOS: staic framework and dynamic framework?

Tags: objective-c

Recently, I decide to make a framework for login module. I add the image resources to the framework, but I could not get it by code.  I change the build the setting. mach-o type static library into dynamic library. I can get the image.

1. It is easier to make a moudle with dynamic framework than static framework.
   but I google and find the dynamic framework made by developer is different with the Apple's dynamic framework. the app contain custom dynamic framework can not upload to Appstore ? Is it true?
   who can answer my question? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So the question is how load image from framework or do you able to use dynamic frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic frameworks are extremely common in AppStore apps. What you're probably seeing in posts is that you cannot manually load frameworks at runtime on iOS (i.e. there's no access to `dlopen`). They all have to be loaded at link time. You also cannot ship "shared" frameworks, where multiple apps share a single copy (like Apple's system frameworks). Each app must contain all of its custom frameworks.

But you can certainly ship dynamic frameworks in your bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when should I use dynamic libraries or static libraries for modular development?

Comment: You can't use dynamic *libraries* directly, but you can use dynamic *frameworks* (which bundle a library). As far as when should you create a framework, if you're developing by yourself, probably never. There's a lot of complexity still (it's getting better, but it's still complicated), and you won't get enough benefit back. Creating frameworks makes the most sense when different developers work on the framework than work on the app. Xcode+SwiftPM may eventually make modules lightweight enough to be worth it for just modularity, but we're not there yet IMO.